# Screen Sharing without Username and Password login

Tags: password, remote-desktop, login, login-screen

When I connect to a Mac with Screen Sharing enabled, I get a screen which asks for the Mac's username and password which I need to type in before I can see the actual desktop.

Is there any way to stop this so I do not need to login?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't really be secure, would it, if you could just share into any machine you liked?

Answer (score 1):

If you have identical accounts with the same credentials set up on both Macs, and you are currently logged in as that account, I do not believe that it will prompt you at all when you connect to the other Mac.